# hddtemp and smartctl with usb to sata external hdd

Tags: external-hdd, smart

I can use hddtemp to read temperture various usb hdd's using 
hddtemp sata:/dev/sdX
and as well smartctl (GsmartControl as well) does work when I use "-d sat" option.
Can I somehow make this a default for hddtemp, or override somethig in settings permanently? I would like to see temperature in xfce4-sensors-plugin, or, at least, by simple wildcard in /dev/sd?

I do not use other than sata hdd's?(and it seems making no problem if called with standard usb flash key which does tell nothing either).
I sometimes change drives and would have to manually change commands to let them work if usb drive moves elsewhere.. But the most wanted is xfce4 plugin to see them all.

hddtemp /dev/sd? does work perfect but onlty with real sata ports, tells :drive does not support SMART for each USB.
hddtemp sata:/dev/sd? does not like the command syntax. Perhaps I am noob and do not know how to use command line?
hddtemp /dev/sd[a-c] sata:/dev/sdd  -it does work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `/dev/sd?` matches the file names that exist, but there's no file named `sata:anything`...

```
for i in /dev/sd? ; do hddtemp sata:$i; done
```

should work though.